# jQuery ui onSelect() function - I need two things to happen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having a hard time getting two things to happen when an onSelect() method is triggered.  I can get either of these functions to work when they're alone, but can't get them both to happen.  Please see the code.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RxTax/119/

```
<div class="formInput">
    <label for="startDatePicker">Check-in:</label>
    <input type="text" id="start" name="check-in" size="30" class="textInput">
</div>

<div class="formInput">
    <label for="endDatePicker">Check-out:</label>
    <input type="text" id="end" name="check-out" size="30" class="textInput">
</div>

<script>
    $("#start").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
            $("#end").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        }
    });


$( "#start" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#end").datepicker( "setDate" , dateText )
    }
});

    $("#end").datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the option in the second block of code, not adding to it. If you want to do two things, put them in one function.

Comment: I tried that but didn't have success.  I'm pretty unfamiliar with writing scripts for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try abstracting them out into separate functions, and then just calling those functions within the `onSelect`:

```
$(function(){
    var $end = $('#end'),
        dateFuncs = {
            endDate:function(dt){
                var selectedDate = new Date(dt),
                    endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());

                $end.datepicker('option','minDate',endDate);
            },
            setDate:function(dt){
                $end.datepicker('setDate',dt);
            }
        };

    $('#start').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(date,inst){
            dateFuncs.endDate(date);
            dateFuncs.setDate(date);
        }
    });
});
```

This allows you create as many other functions you want, only has a single binding event, and keeps code maintainance simple.

Something else you might try is using the object method:

```
$('#start').datepicker({
    onSelect:function(dateText,inst){
        var selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());

        $('#end').datepicker({
            setDate:dateText,
            option:{
                minDate:endDate
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I can't say I've ever seen people use this before, but knowing the jQuery methods like I do I can almost guarantee you can do it. If you can, this would accomplish the same task: single binding with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Do both in one `onSelect` function.

```
$("#start").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var selectedDate = inst.datepicker('getDate');
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
        $("#end").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate )
                 .datePicker("setDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```